# How to backup datastore with filter

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I declare table on datastore,
such as  |id|date|value1|value2|...|

I want to backup only this week.("date > today-7" and "date < today")

Can I backup with filtering?
(Datastore Admin or something.)

Comment: namespace is useful?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with Datastore admin, nor with Import/Export. Your option here is to use Dataflow template [Datastore to Text](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/provided-templates#cloud-datastore-to-cloud-storage-text).

Be careful with this. For your query, you may be hitting a narrow range of keys (not sure if you have 500 entities over the last 7 days, or 1million on one of them), which may cause high latency and read timeouts retrieving the entities, as Dataflow will try to pull them all massively parallel-ly. If you can break this into queries that gather every other day or somehow distribute the reads a little better, you'll get better results.